# Equivalent of by.name selector in playwright

Tags: css-selectors, playwright, playwright-test

I have been trying to learn playwright and during the course of implementation I am trying  to write a test case which find an input element by Name and fills it with some values

Unfortunately, the element has only class and name attributes. I have been trying to find a way to read it but did not found anything on the docs or I might have missed

Kindly help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not direct answer, but a work around.
You can specify your css selector to search for the name attribute:

Structure is:

```
<tag>[attribute='value']
```

For example:
This html (which is on this page if you view the dom):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Is identified with this css:

```
meta[name='viewport']
```

It is also possible without a tag and only by the name, see the following example:

```
await page.click(`[name='my-value']`);
```

[image: screenshot of devtools with identifier]

Comment: one more question - I found multiple element with the same name and playwright used the first one, which happened to be a hidden field, which is causing the same to fail. is there anything to tell playwright to selected a specific one ? I tried giving the following `await page.fill("[name='username'] :visible", "admin");` but obviously its not working, any further suggestions?

Comment: @vivek try a different locator?  A more specific one?  - just using `[name='username']` will find any element of any tag with that name and, as you've seen, might not pick the one you want. Easiest solution is to write a better, more specific identifier. If you share your html (probably as a new question) someone will help - alternatively, I strongly suggest you invest a couple of hours and learn how to identify web elements. This is an excellent learning resource and will teach you do to it like a pro: https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/

Comment: Also - `page.$$(selector)` is how you can collect all elements and iterate through. https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-query-selector-all

Comment: ya that has been a challenge, unfortunately we are dependent on  a 3rd party application which seems to have caused these set backs ! Thanks for the help. made quite a bit of progress.

Answer (score 3):

If it's helpful for anyone else with the same issue, this works for me. Assuming there is an input with the name attribute, username:

```
await page.locator("[name='username']").fill("Some value")
```